# WPF Ribbon changes title bar style in XP

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp

[EDITED]

After several tries, I found out it was the Microsoft WPF Ribbon that causes the title bar style not rendering correctly.

Application without Ribbon in XP: [image]

Application with Ribbon in XP: [image]

I have already set the theme to be XP style. Still not fix. It is a bug in Microsoft Ribbon or am I missing something? On Window 7, on the other hand, renders OK.

Develop on WPF C# .NET 4, VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care? this is a user setting to have Aero enabled or not in Vista or 7 and theming enabled or not in XP like in 2 and 3 pictures you sent.

In general you should ignore this. Office 2007 and 2010 with ribbon UI renders the same but because ribbons are skinning the application windows completely.

My suggestion is to either use skins and do the same or simply ignote this because if I use Vista with Aero enabled I would not like your App to look like classic Win2000 applications.

Comment: I set in XP to use XP-Style. But when I ignore the theme, somehow my application display classic theme, which neither the user or I want to see. I CANNOT get the application to display XP style regardless of whether user set it to display XP style. This is the reason why I try to configure the theme. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is anyways an issue with the window title bar as it will use the default theme of the OS you are using.

I suggest you to neutralize the style by implementing a custom window style that takes the windows 7 look n feel for all windows ion your applications. Have a look at the [MessageBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox) control from latest extended WPF toolkit.

It has a windows 7 style themse that looks exactly same on all the above OS if you use

```
    Window.AllowsTransparency="False"
    Window.WindowStyle="None"
    Window.Style="{StaticResource Windows7WindowStyle}"
```

Comment: I cannot even turn off WindowStyle. It only works in 7 but not XP. See edited question.

Comment: I am being successfully using these styles on XP, 7 and Vista. What error do you receive when you specify `WindowStyle` as `None`?